# Flutter google maps: Change selected marker icon dynamically

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am using google map package on my flutter project. I have a page in which google map is shown in  a full screen and carousel of products (horizontally scrollable) over it. Clicking each marker will slide carousel to reveal the product info widget.

I have following codes

```
  CameraPosition _productLocation;
  Set<Marker> markers = Set();
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  BitmapDescriptor defaultIcon =
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed); //default marker
  BitmapDescriptor selectedIcon =
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueViolet); //selected marker


 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _productLocation = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 16,
    );


    if (widget.productList.length > 0) {
      widget.productList.asMap().forEach((index, v) {
        Marker resultMarker = Marker(
            icon: _currentIndex == index ? selectedIcon : defaultIcon,
            consumeTapEvents: true,
            markerId: MarkerId(v.slug),
            position:
                LatLng(double.parse(v.latitude), double.parse(v.longitude)),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _currentIndex = index;
              });

              buttonCarouselController.animateToPage(index);
            });
        // Add it to Set
        markers.add(resultMarker);
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: GoogleMap(
              markers: markers,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: _productLocation,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Problem**

The first time when we enter the page, i.e. if  `_currentIndex==0`, the first marker is blue in color and first product info widget is shown, rest are red color. Something that doesn't work is when I click another marker, I want this marker to turn blue and rest all red. So in short, I want selected marker to be blue. Can anybody please throw some light on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your markers set their color in `initState()` which only happens once for the Widget. (so the `setState()` fires, but the `markers` Set is unchanged)

You need to move the `Set<Marker> markers` population either into `build()` or refactor it so that it get's re-populated from the marker onTap()